# Monitor outgoing internet request in Python

Tags: python, linux

What are some useful methods or libraries that can be used to track IP request from a personal computer. Ideally I would like the option to block or pause a specific outgoing request before/after some checks are carried out. I've seen Twisted, but I'm not sure if its exactly what I'm looking for just yet, or if there exist simpler methods for doing this. I'm not looking for a standalone application as there are other features that will be build around this for a specific purpose.

Language: Preferably in Python, but C/C++ are possible options as well.

OS: The current target is Linux (ubuntu). However cross-platform options would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted will make it easy to get up and running right away while making it possible for you to intercept, delay, or block requests:  http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.proxy.Proxy.html